# Sleep and Clock Method

Tags: ubuntu, c, time

```
int main(void){

    int start = clock();
    sleep(5);
    int end = clock();

    printf("%d", (end - start));
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code in ubuntu, I get the result 30; however, I suspend the process in 5 seconds by sleep() method. Why is the result equal to 30 ?

How can I compute suspended time of the process ?

Comment: Have [a look at `man 3 clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) (but this is really a C question and not on-topic at U&L).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clock()` function returns the amount of CPU time used since the process started.  To get the number in seconds, you should divide by the constant `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

In most cases, no or very little CPU time will be used in a call to sleep (I always get zero back).

You could use `time()` to get seconds of wall clock time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

  time_t start = time(NULL);
  sleep(5);
  time_t end = time(NULL);

  printf("%.1f\n", difftime(end, start));

  return 0;
}
```

For timing short intervals [`gettimeofday()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) may be more useful as it gives microsecond granularity instead of just seconds, like `time()`.

Comment: what is the value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC?

Comment: @Debian_yadav It's a constant (well, a preprocessor macro really) defined in `time.h`.  But you only need this if you really want to use `clock()` to measure _CPU time_ (as opposed to wall clock time).

Comment: Can we relate it to CPU frequency like 2.4GHz

Comment: @Debian_yadav No. It's related to the resolution of the timer in the C library.